# how to set multiple selector on WebTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am making form test set by this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#forms)

My selector html is here

```
<select id="se83c9b2db8_placeCats" name="se83c9b2db8[placeCats][]" class=" form-control" multiple="multiple" >
<option value="20">test1</option>
<option value="21">test2</option>
<option value="22">test3</option>
<option value="23">test4</option>
<option value="24">test5</option></select>
```

Then I tried to use select().

However both two sentences shows the 
`Unreachable field error`

Does anyone helps??

```
    $form['se83c9b2db8[placeCats][]']->select("20");//  InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "2"
    $form['se83c9b2db8[placeCats][0]']->select("20"); //  InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field ""
```

StackTrace

```
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/FormFieldRegistry.php:84
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Form.php:330
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/tests/DefaultTest.php:78
```

Comment: Try `dd($form['se83c9b2db8[placeCats]'])` and see if there is something inside.

Comment: Any success with `$form['se83c9b2db8_placeCats']`?

Comment: `$form['se83c9b2db8_placeCats']->select("20')`. works well thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, is it impossible to choose by name like `test1` instead of value.

Comment: but `test1` is a value, not a name (in your case)